# <p:chart> doesn't create LineChartModel correctly

Tags: jsf, primefaces, charts

I'm trying to draw a chart on JSF page using PrimeFaces `<p:chart>` tag:

```
 <p:chart type="line" model="#{chartViewBean.lineModel}" style="width:400px;height:300px"/>
```

and here is my `createLineModel` method:

```
private void createLineModel() {
    lineModel = new LineChartModel();
    LineChartSeries series = new LineChartSeries();
    for (ReportTotal reportTotal : reportBean.getReportTotals()) {
        series.set(reportTotal.getDate(), reportTotal.getTotal());
        System.out.println(reportTotal.getDate());
    }
    lineModel.addSeries(series);
    lineModel.setTitle("Orders total");
    lineModel.setAnimate(true);
    lineModel.getAxis(AxisType.Y).setLabel("Values");
    DateAxis axis = new DateAxis("Dates");
    axis.setTickFormat("%b %#d, %y");
    axis.setMax("2016-12-31");
    lineModel.getAxes().put(AxisType.X, axis);
}
```

and I got such chart:
[image]

But when I set hardcoded data to series:

```
 series.set("2016-01-12", 65);
 series.set("2016-03-18", 74);
 series.set("2016-06-24", 24);
 series.set("2016-11-30", 51);
```

It looks pretty good:
[image]

When I output `System.out.println(reportTotal.getDate());` I also got the same data as in hardcode:

```
2015-12-01
2015-12-02
2015-12-03
2015-12-04
2015-12-05
```

What's wrong with my series setting?

Comment: Hi, Does reportTotal.getDate() return a Date or a String?

Comment: your points are very close and the scale is huge. I bet your 'dates' are interpreted as integers and close to 0 miliseconds and thus on 01 01 1970…  and

Comment: Hi, Mahendran! Thank you a lot, you turned me on a right way. It returned `java.sql.Date` and when I added `.toString()` method it begin working! But now I need to set `axis.setMax("2015-12-10")` otherwise points are too close to each other. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the x axis is pointing to String values,

```
  series.set(reportTotal.getDate(), reportTotal.getTotal());
```

should be changed to

```
  series.set(reportTotal.getDate().toString(), reportTotal.getTotal());
```

Comment: thank you, that is exactly what I did when Mahendran advice me to.

Comment: @DimaSan: Then please accept the answer. And if it was very helpful, you can also upvote...